# How to set date range corresponding to the program period in datepicker php

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I want to make jquery datepicker in php that only show 1 month corresponding to the program period. 
For example, my program has a periodical system that has been saved in database. For October 2014 the system period is set as "2012.10" mark as period = "1". The next period = "2" is for November 2014 set as "2014.11". In the system, it has a feature to close month so it isn't bound with the server datetime. And let it say, we are in "2014.10" period. 
So I want to make datepicker that only show date in "October 2014".

Here is my script :

```
$("#tanggal_pembelian").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    stepMonths: 0,
    showAnim:"slideDown",
    showOptions:{direction:"up"} 
});
```

The problem is :

If I set "stepMonths: 0", trouble comes whenever the server datetime have change to another month = "November 2014" so that datepicker only show "November 2014" period only. But the system period still in "October 2014" cause I still don't run close month feature in the system.

Hopefully somebody can help answering my question. I really appreciate it. Thanks before.

Comment: "I want to make jquery datepicker in php".  jQuery and PHP have nothing to do with each other.  jQuery/Javascript is client-side, PHP is server-side.

Comment: indeed but i want to send php information (system period) to jquery so that datepicker only show the corresponding month to system period

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want datepicker to only show one month and that month is whatever PHP tells it.

Comment: In which case a simple ajax call should do the trick.

Comment: yeah, that's right.. sorry about my grammar that make you all complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating some hidden input in html to tell jquery datepicker for minDate and maxDate value.

Here is the code :

```
$("#tanggal_pembelian").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    stepMonths: 0,
    minDate: new Date($('#startdate').val()),
    maxDate: new Date($('#enddate').val()),
    showAnim:"slideDown",
    showOptions:{direction:"up"} 
});
```

Next we must search the beginning of month and end of month in current period. 
After that, just put the value in hidden input textfield :

```
$prd = explode(".",$_SESSION[period]);
$startdate = date("Y-m-01", mktime(0,0,0,$prd[1],1,$prd[0]));
$enddate = date("Y-m-t", mktime(0,0,0,$prd[1],1,$prd[0]));
echo "<input type=hidden id='startdate' name='startdate' maxlength=20 value='$startdate' readonly>";
echo "<input type=hidden id='enddate' name='enddate' maxlength=20 value='$enddate' readonly>";
```

Maybe my answer can help anyone else that have the same problem... Thanks all...